# Assign result of regexp_split_to_array() to Pl/pgSQL array variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array, regular-expression

How do I create an array and then put a result of a function into it?
I'm doing it like this:

```
array text[];
select regexp_split_to_array('whatever this is it splits into array with spaces', E'\\s+')
    into array;
```

But obviously it doesn't work, when I try to

```
raise notice '%', array[1];
```

It's just not how it's done.

Comment: You forgot to mention your version of Postgres, as well as what happens for you. Result? Error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`array`** is a *reserved word*.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) You cannot use it as variable name in PL/pgSQL.
This works:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _arr text[];
BEGIN
   SELECT regexp_split_to_array('this splits into array with spaces', '\s+')
   INTO _arr;

   RAISE NOTICE '%', _arr[1];
END
$do$;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1961)

Also simplified `E'\\s+'` --> `'\s+'`.
[`standard_conforming_strings = ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) is the default since Postgres 9.1 and should be the universal setting by now.